# What is the specific function of next() in NodeJS/SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've been watching a SailsJS tutorial and for some user authentication I saw that function applied but I did not get what is the specific function of `next();`

Comment: Goes to the next handler.

Comment: Callback to the next function lol, see [here](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/02/essential-node-js-patterns-and-snippets/) for examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of next is to continue processing a request -- this allows things like middleware to work.

Here's an example.

Imagine you have a simple Express.js app that looks like this:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hi!');
});

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  res.send('there!');
});
```

The above app has 2 routes, and each does something particular.

Now, what if we wanted to create a special function that prints hello world to the console before every request is executed? To do that, we'd need to modify either both routes above, or create a middleware like so:

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('hello, world!');
  next();  // continue processing
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hi!');
});

app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  res.send('there!');
});
```

Now, what happens is that, for each request, the function we defined above will be called BEFORE any of our route code, and once it makes the call to `next()`, that means we'll then run our route code.

Nifty, right?

At a basic level, the `next` object is just the 'next function' to execute, so when you say `next()`, you're telling express to keep processing the user request, essentially.

Comment: So this is a great explanation. But what happens if we forgot to put it in the middleware ? Blocking behaviour ?

Comment: Nope! If you call next() and there's nothing left to process, then nothing will happen. So you're good to go!

Comment: And what if you dont call next ?

Comment: If you don't call next(), then processing will simply stop there -- your route code will never get called =)